# mod_rewrite a sub directoy to child subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a following sub domain and folder structure

https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/dashboard

I want to mod_rewrite to this

https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/

So that everything in "dashboard" loads, in "area"

I would like the .htaccess file to live in the area folder, as there are multiple companyNames

I've tried placing the following .htaccess in companyName1/area

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-s
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dashboard/%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dashboard/$1 [L]
```

However when visiting https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/ it just loads the index.html of that folder, and not of the /dashboard folder

Comment: Could you please do confirm if you have any other Rules apart from these in your htaccess rules file?

Comment: No I don’t have any other rules at all

Comment: So you want to only serve url `https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/dashboard` in browser and which should redirect to `https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/`? Also in backend from which file(eg: index.php OR any other php file) it should be served?

Comment: Yes - all files in “dashboard” should be loaded under “area” - however I don’t want to redirect, I just want to hide the word “dashboard” from the url but keep my files actually located in “dashboard”

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to keep these rules at the top of your htaccess file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /companyName1/area/
##For external redirect to area link.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.*/dashboard/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/dashboard/?$ /$1/? [R=301,L]
##For internal rewrite to dashboard folder here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that produces the following error

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @PaulF, make sure your htaccess is present in along side with `companyName1` folder(not inside it) and try my edited rules once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have now tried this aswell with your edit and still recieve "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @PaulF, you mentioned you want to hide `dashboard` from url if that's the case then redirect has to happen in browser. Is it ok if we keep the url same? I mean till `dashbord` in browser?

Comment: I am happy to try anything that will turn https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/dashboard in to https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/ without having to move any project files :)

Comment: @PaulF, ok sure, please try my edited rules once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: The redirect from area/dashboard to /area works, however when on /area, again Internal Server Error

Comment: @PaulF, so you simply want to see files when someone hits urls? OR you have futher links for example: `https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/dashboard/TEST` which should be change to `https://subdomain.maindomain.com/companyName1/area/TEST` and could be served by test.php in backend(just adding it as an exmple here)?

Comment: For testing purposes i am just trying to make a blank index.html file appear before using .php file

Comment: @PaulF, ok sure, try my edited rules now, this will be served by index.html you can change it to index.php file also, try it out once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Internal Server Error again

Comment: @PaulF, could you please try my edited code once? I have removed one condition from it, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Im afraid it is still giving me Internal Server Error

Comment: @PaulF, oh sorry. Trying my best here, edited code a bit here test it once. Also make sure your index.html, htaccess both are in along side with folder `companyName1` if NOT then we need to give complete path for index.html like: `companyName1/area/dashboard/etc_etc/index.html`, try it out once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @PaulF, Could you please do let me know if my edited code has worked for you? As mentioned previously it has worked in my local, let me know how it went.